# Wine Crashes XMonad

Tags: arch-linux, wine, xmonad

I've set up xmonad on arch, but when I start an .exe file through wine, xmonad stops responding (I can still type and interact with the application, but not switch windows, open dmenu, etc.).  I've looked at the FAQ for xmonad, but I'm not using unclutter and i think I've handled the pipes problem.

here is my xmonad.hs:

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.ManageHook
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageHelpers
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog
import XMonad.Hooks.FadeInactive
import XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops
import XMonad.Util.Run
import XMonad.Util.EZConfig
import XMonad.Layout.Monitor
import XMonad.Layout.NoBorders(smartBorders)
import Graphics.X11.ExtraTypes.XF86
import System.IO
import Data.Default

main = xmonad  =<< statusBar "xmobar" barPP toggleStrutsKey myConfig
toggleStrutsKey XConfig {XMonad.modMask = mm} = (mm,xK_b)
barPP = xmobarPP
        { ppOutput = (\_ -> return ())
        , ppTitle = xmobarColor "white" "" . shorten 5
        }
myXmonadBar = "xmobar /home/iam/.xmobarrc"
myTerm = "urxvt"
myWorkspaces =
  [ "1:Main"
  , "2:Alt"
  , "3:Music"
  , "4:Chat"
  , "5:Web"
  , "6:Code"
  ]
myConfig = ewmh def
    { manageHook = (isFullscreen --> doFullFloat) <+> manageDocks <+> manageHook'
    , handleEventHook =  handleEventHook def <+> fullscreenEventHook
    , workspaces = myWorkspaces
    , layoutHook = smartBorders $ avoidStruts $ layoutHook def
    , modMask = mod4Mask
    , terminal = myTerm
    , normalBorderColor = "#1F034E"
    , focusedBorderColor = "#958500"
    } `additionalKeys`
    [ ((mod4Mask .|. shiftMask, xK_z), spawn "xscreensaver-command -lock")
    , ((0, xF86XK_AudioLowerVolume), spawn "amixer set Master 2%- unmute")
    , ((0, xF86XK_AudioRaiseVolume), spawn "amixer set Master 2%+ unmute")
    , ((0, xF86XK_AudioMute), spawn "amixer set Master toggle")
    ]

manageHook' :: ManageHook
manageHook' = composeAll . concat $
              [ [className =? "Vivaldi-stable" --> doShift "5:Web"]
              --, [className =? c --> doShift "4:Term" | c <- terminals]
              , [className =? "Emacs" --> doShift "6:Code"]
              , [className =? music --> doShift "3:Music" | music <- ["Rhythmbox"]]
              --, [resource =? r --> doIgnore | r <- myIgnores]
              ]
  where
    terminals = [ "urxvt"
                , "gnome-terminal"
                , "terminator"
                , "xterm"
                ]
    myIgnores = [ "desktop"
                , "desktop_window"
                , "trayer"
                ]
    browsers = [ "Vivaldi-stable"
               , "Firefox"
               ]
```